# Button onclick also presses enter on a input field

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api

I want my button so that when it is clicked, it will also press enter on an input field. I am using Google Maps API, place search box.(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

I also added in code so that the API will ask permission for your location. Here is my button and input field code.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" id="go" value="Food near me">Click</button>
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('pac-input').value = this.value;
};
```

As you can see, when the button is pressed, "Food near me" is added to the pac-input input. But in order for it to display the results, I have to press the enter key inside the input field, I want the results to show when I mouse click the button

Answer (score 0):

instead of pressing enter to trigger your textbox function you may create a shared function to be called by enter key on textbox or button click like

```
function getData(){
 //Get DataHere;
}

function buttonClick(){
 getData();
}


function enterKeyFunc(e){
 if(e.which==13)
 {
  getData();
 }
}
```

and if you really need to simulate keypress event check this post

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

**Enter key pressing:**

```
$("#pac-input").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13)
    {
        //Do  your button click option
    }
});
```

Comment: i think he wants to make the opposite to press the enter key with button

Comment: @HassanElsherbiny i think he wants the result by button click.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has `trigger` function to execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type..
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/